# How can I force Visual Studio to reference an assembly without using its version?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a VC++ project and I need to add a reference to a managed dll. This dll has a version number which changes every build. When I add it to my project, its version is saved and if I replace it with another one (with a different version number) the project cannot compile because it doesn't find the dll with the version previously saved.
Is there a way to add a reference without a specific version?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you tried deleting the previous reference and then adding the new reference?

Comment: Yes, it is the only way to make it working, but, since I often change the dll, I'd like to avoid that step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# IDE has the "Specific Version" property for a reference but the C++/CLI build system doesn't support that.  There is a workaround, you can use the #using directive in source code to load an assembly reference.  This by design cannot check the assembly version of the reference assembly.  Normally that's a problem but not in your case.  The MSDN page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab9swk4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I don't know whether this works with C++ projects -- we have C# code that references C++, but we haven't done the other way around. But just in case it's easy, I'll offer this:

With C#-to-C# references, normally you would make sure both projects are in the same solution, and then add a reference using the "Projects" tab of the Add Reference dialog (*not* the "Browse" tab). This way, the build system has a reference to the project in the solution (which knows its own current version number), rather than having a reference to the filename+version; and then it can cope with version number changes just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately the reference is not part of the project.